# Keep position fixed through absolute position failed in IE6

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, absolute

I'm using javascript to compute `bottom` property to keep element like fixed position in IE6, here is my code:

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var targetBottom = 200;

window.onscroll = function (e) {
    scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    target.style.bottom = targetBottom - scrollTop + "px";
}
```

However, this could't work in IE6, but in IE7 and above. So what's wrong with my code? How can I make it work in IE6?

Comment: Try document.body.scrollTop; for ie6 :)

Comment: Just curious as to why you would still be coding for IE6?

Comment: @FrankConijn , cuz I am in China